# Bootstrap validator error on mozilla and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bootstrapvalidator

I am using bootstrap validator and it works fine in Chrome, but my users are experiencing troubles in Firefox and Safari since validator goes to `isDefaultPrevented` event every time.

This is my html:

```
<form action="viajesBusquedaFinaliza.php" id="transfer-form" method="GET" role="form" style="display: none;">
    <div class="f-row form-group">
        <div class="one-half">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminoscondiciones" />
            <label for="terminoscondiciones">Acepto los terminos y condiciones</label>
            <a onclick="abrirTerminos();" title="Terminos y Condiciones"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="one-half">
            <input type="checkbox" name="avisoprivacidad" />
            <label for="avisoprivacidad">Acepto el aviso de privacidad</label>
            <a onclick="abrirAviso();" title="Aviso de privacidad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="f-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="esTransferencia" id="esTransferencia" value="1">
        <div class="one-fifth">
            <input type="submit" id="submitFormTransferencia" name="submitFormTransferencia" class="btn color medium right submit-button" value="Pagar" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my jQuery code inside a document ready block:

```
/* Validator */
$('#transfer-form').bootstrapValidator({
    submitButtons: 'button[type="submit"]',
    feedbackIcons: {
        required: 'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        terminoscondiciones: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Debes aceptar los términos y condiciones'
                }
            }
        },
        avisoprivacidad: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Debes aceptar el aviso de privacidad'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // alert('prevented');
    } else {
        $("#submitFormTransferencia").prop( "disabled", true);
        // $("#submitFormTransferencia").attr('action','viajesBusquedaFinaliza.php');
        $.ajax({
            url: "viajesBusquedaPagarRespuesta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#transfer-form').serializeArray(),
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status == 1) {

                } else {
                    alert(data.status + " - " + data.message);
                    $("#submitFormTransferencia").prop( "disabled", false);                        
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In Chrome it works every time but if I run in Mozilla, it goes straight to the action defined on the form, and `e.isDefaultPrevented()` is always triggered even if the form is correctly validated.